# Manually create a pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to manually create a pyspark dataframe given certain data:

```py
row_in = [(1566429545575348), (40.353977), (-111.701859)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(row_in)
schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("time_epocs", DecimalType(), True),
        StructField("lat", DecimalType(), True),
        StructField("long", DecimalType(), True),
    ]
)
df_in_test = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

This gives an error when I try to display the dataframe, so I am not sure how to do this.

However, the [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame) seems to be a bit convoluted to me, and I got similar errors when I tried to follow those instructions.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: your code should work if `row_in=[(1566429545575348, 40.353977,-111.701859)]`

Comment: This did not work even with using  row_in=[(1566429545575348, 40.353977,-111.701859)]

Comment: The real probleme comes from the fact that `(1)` is an int, not a tuple. when you only have 1 element, you need to add a coma to create the tuple `(1,)`

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Simple dataframe creation:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, "foo"),  # create your data here, be consistent in the types.
        (2, "bar"),
    ],
    ["id", "label"]  # add your column names here
)

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- label: string (nullable = true)

df.show()
+---+-----+                                                                     
| id|label|
+---+-----+
|  1|  foo|
|  2|  bar|
+---+-----+
```

According to [official doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame):

- when schema is a list of column names, the type of each column will be inferred from data. *(example above ↑)*
- When schema is `pyspark.sql.types.DataType` or a datatype string, it must match the real data. *(examples below ↓)*

```py
# Example with a datatype string
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, "foo"),  # Add your data here
        (2, "bar"),
    ],  
    "id int, label string",  # add column names and types here
)

# Example with pyspark.sql.types
from pyspark.sql import types as T
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, "foo"),  # Add your data here
        (2, "bar"),
    ],
    T.StructType(  # Define the whole schema within a StructType
        [
            T.StructField("id", T.IntegerType(), True),
            T.StructField("label", T.StringType(), True),
        ]
    ),
)


df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)  # type is forced to Int
 |-- label: string (nullable = true)
```

---

Additionally, you can create your dataframe from Pandas dataframe, schema will be inferred from Pandas dataframe's types :

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


pdf = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [np.random.randint(10) for x in range(10)],
        "col2": [np.random.randint(100) for x in range(10)],
    }
)


df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)

df.show()
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   6|   4|
|   1|  39|
|   7|   4|
|   7|  95|
|   6|   3|
|   7|  28|
|   2|  26|
|   0|   4|
|   4|  32|
+----+----+
```

Answer (score 7):

To elaborate/build off of @Steven's answer:

```py
field = [
    StructField("MULTIPLIER", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("DESCRIPTION", StringType(), True),
]
schema = StructType(field)
multiplier_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)
```

Will create a blank dataframe.

We can now simply add a row to it:

```py
l = [(2.3, "this is a sample description")]
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
multiplier_df_temp = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
multiplier_df = wtp_multiplier_df.union(wtp_multiplier_df_temp)
```

Comment: is that unclosed parenthesis part of the syntax?

Comment: why would you need to join `multiplier_df_temp` with an empty dataframe ? you already created the line with the proper schema. the `union` is useless.

Comment: This approach should be avoided because it's needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 7):

This answer demonstrates how to create a PySpark DataFrame with `createDataFrame`, `create_df` and `toDF`.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([("joe", 34), ("luisa", 22)], ["first_name", "age"])

df.show()
```

```
+----------+---+
|first_name|age|
+----------+---+
|       joe| 34|
|     luisa| 22|
+----------+---+
```

You can also pass `createDataFrame` a RDD and schema to construct DataFrames with more precision:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
    Row(name='Allie', age=2),
    Row(name='Sara', age=33),
    Row(name='Grace', age=31)])

schema = schema = StructType([
   StructField("name", StringType(), True),
   StructField("age", IntegerType(), False)])

df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

df.show()
```

```
+-----+---+
| name|age|
+-----+---+
|Allie|  2|
| Sara| 33|
|Grace| 31|
+-----+---+
```

`create_df` from my [Quinn](https://github.com/MrPowers/quinn) project allows for the best of both worlds - it's concise and fully descriptive:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from quinn.extensions import *

df = spark.create_df(
    [("jose", "a"), ("li", "b"), ("sam", "c")],
    [("name", StringType(), True), ("blah", StringType(), True)]
)

df.show()
```

```
+----+----+
|name|blah|
+----+----+
|jose|   a|
|  li|   b|
| sam|   c|
+----+----+
```

`toDF` doesn't offer any advantages over the other approaches:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
    Row(name='Allie', age=2),
    Row(name='Sara', age=33),
    Row(name='Grace', age=31)])
df = rdd.toDF()
df.show()
```

```
+-----+---+
| name|age|
+-----+---+
|Allie|  2|
| Sara| 33|
|Grace| 31|
+-----+---+
```

Answer (score 3):

With formatting

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, IntegerType, StringType

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, "foo"),
        (2, "bar"),
    ],
    StructType(
        [
            StructField("id", IntegerType(), False),
            StructField("txt", StringType(), False),
        ]
    ),
)
print(df.dtypes)
df.show()
```

Comment: This is the only solution (I can see) that shows how to create the `spark` variable, all of the other solutions assume you have it already. Thanks for thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Extending @Steven's Answer:

```
data = [(i, 'foo') for i in range(1000)] # random data

columns = ['id', 'txt']    # add your columns label here

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
```

Note: When `schema` is a list of column-names, the type of each column will be inferred from data.

If you want to specifically define schema then do this:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType
schema = StructType([StructField("id", IntegerType(), True), StructField("txt", StringType(), True)])
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
```

Outputs:

```
>>> df1
DataFrame[id: int, txt: string]
>>> df
DataFrame[id: bigint, txt: string]
```

Answer (score 0):

for beginners, a full example importing data from file:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import (
    ShortType,
    StringType,
    StructType,
    StructField,
    TimestampType,
)

import os

here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("id", ShortType(), nullable=False),
        StructField("string", StringType(), nullable=False),
        StructField("datetime", TimestampType(), nullable=False),
    ]
)

# read file or construct rows manually
df = spark.read.csv(os.path.join(here, "data.csv"), schema=schema, header=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answers:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    data=[
        Row(id=1, label="foo"),
        Row(id=2, label="bar")
    ],
    schema=StructType([
        StructField(name="id", dataType=IntegerType(), nullable=True),
        StructField(name="label", dataType=StringType(), nullable=True)
    ])
)
```