# Create a DataFrame from Lists

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I try to create spark dataframe where I want to convert a list into a column.

Code:

```
def create_id(n):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(50))

list_a = [create_id(25) for x in range(100)]
list_b = [create_id(25) for x in range(100)]

df = sc.parallelize([["a", list_a], ["b", list_b]]).toDF()
```

This results in

```
    _1                                                _2
0   a   [dv2vtdl3sobadlw1svs39emp2n9ogwzzek8b6gvug7xkp...
1   b   [kdv6b9ehqx1t8kbxd77ha8435bhduyxp0ilv6e09wpejx..
```

This will create 100 columns, not 100 rows:

```
df = sc.parallelize([list_a, list_b]).toDF()
```

Does anyone know how I can create a DataFrame with a two columns and 100 rows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manually create a pyspark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959759/manually-create-a-pyspark-dataframe)

Comment: I have already seen this, but this is not suitable for me, since it uses tuples and the index of the tuple is responsible for the column the value will be in.

Comment: then, you did not understand how it works cause that's exactly how it should be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using post [Manually create a pyspark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959759/manually-create-a-pyspark-dataframe):

```py
def create_id(n):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(n))

list_a = [create_id(25) for _ in range(100)]
list_b = [create_id(25) for _ in range(100)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(zip(list_a,list_b), ['a', 'b'])

# OR

list_a_b = [(create_id(25), create_id(25)) for _ in range(100)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(list_a_b, ['a', 'b'])

df.show()
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                   a|                   b|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|68blfnltq9fh81c4y...|3fl1wb5h2euy3sgd7...|
|ac37fb7qif71zzjpr...|xbqzzgiq9s6t5jiqm...|
|72rk28znzr6jjsi69...|5wvl528eg5y3p1lsk...|
|fioqnla3ijvl5769s...|1xvs2592uaxadv1o4...|
|7der8ld8fd6vl6g9d...|lrup85xitjz1uhsfl...|
|gycdap4hodaxxggw8...|h2oz370tzo6fnpke3...|
|ccvqcyzeynuks63pq...|iut82y2k1irfdvep1...|
|ngq29fnq2usghspgh...|z6j4mibrrjznoc9s8...|
|3qb6xyk5c1kbg0xq1...|l10ouv4w24d66e0ak...|
|u6dcvzede90xa7zz2...|hnh571t9szy0pwjrp...|
|3122g38k47jm24t7f...|tzbxlua574l88qtw1...|
|6pnva6ow83yxexqp1...|0nfj3v59b8jh0qv1g...|
|kl7xyftax3z32ot8o...|0sf6iyiyxpyvyd5kj...|
|36qwiiifgbzba4n8c...|xt4lpkjle8qynnlpo...|
|owsgb02rnov8qrhvw...|1zu4oisit25y2g14i...|
|bcmg0flh4d9tnvnjc...|7lfwx9kf7qens70p8...|
|6sdy1e8i3y1w0rtpr...|gw79bsrx8jlse6ixu...|
|83h5iq10clte1gcpr...|kblufuhlwabu7sv3u...|
|7g20ga0m756f0qsj7...|1fzo40vwtrp0kud8j...|
|07tw66i7dpcphczz1...|9a8c9ditp9dzomxh4...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Comment: thank you, zip is great for this usecase :-)