# Databricks spark dataframe create dataframe by each column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

in pandas , I can do something like this .

```
data = {"col1" : [np.random.randint(10) for x in range(1,10)],
    "col2" : [np.random.randint(100) for x in range(1,10)]}
mypd = pd.DataFrame(data)
mypd
```

and give the two columns

[image]

are there any similar way to create a spark dataframe in pyspark ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manually create a pyspark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959759/manually-create-a-pyspark-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

The answer shared by Steven is brilliant

Additionally if you are comfortable with Pandas

You can directly supply your pandas dataframe to the function [createDataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame.html)

### Spark >= 2.x

```
data = {
    "col1": [np.random.randint(10) for x in range(1, 10)],
    "col2": [np.random.randint(100) for x in range(1, 10)],
}
mypd = pd.DataFrame(data)

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(mypd)

sparkDF.show()

+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   6|   4|
|   1|  39|
|   7|   4|
|   7|  95|
|   6|   3|
|   7|  28|
|   2|  26|
|   0|   4|
|   4|  32|
+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Steven , updated the answer accordingly

Comment: so must need to through pandas first?

Comment: If you are more comfortable with pandas , else you can use the link shared by Steven to directly create a Spark DataFrame bypassing pandas