# how to add column name to the dataframe storing result of correlation of two columns in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have read a csv file and need to find correlation between two columns.

I am using df.stat.corr('Age','Exp') and result is 0.7924058156930612.
But I want to have this result stored in another dataframe with header as "correlation".

### correlation

0.7924058156930612

Comment: If it is a single value, you can create a dataframe from it. You can take reference from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959759/manually-create-a-pyspark-dataframe

Comment: I tried all of it but getting either attribute error or typeerror.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on what @gupta_hemant commented.

You can create a new column as

```py
df.withColumn("correlation", df.stat.corr("Age", "Exp").collect()[0].correlation)
```

(I am guessing the exact syntax here, but it should be something like this)

After reviewing the code, the syntax should be

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn("correlation", F.lit(df.stat.corr("Age", "Exp")))
```

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-3ef0e6dc19ad> in <module>
----> 1 df.withColumn("correlation", df.stat.corr("Age", "Exp").collect()[1].correlation)

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'collect'

Comment: anyhow I tried this but it throws the above error.

Comment: Ah yeah, that is because `.collect()` only works on a dataframe. I assumed `corr()` returned a dataframe, but it doesn't. It returns a `float` as per your error. So you can replace it with `df.withColumn("correlation", df.stat.corr("Age", "Exp"))`

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But I want an individual dataframe to store the result

Comment: Then just follow gupta_hemant's suggestion. You can replace `corrValue` with `df.stat.corr("Age", "Exp")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know.

```
corrValue = df.stat.corr("Age", "Exp")
newDF = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
    (corrValue)
  ],
  ["corr"]
)
```

Comment: TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'float'>   ...getting this again!

Comment: Sorry! There was an error in Jupyter at my end. Reinstalled and got it fixed.

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: Yeah! It worked