# Convert schema in string format to pyspark schema format

Tags: python, database, pyspark, schema

I have a schema in string format:

```
schema_str = """StructType([StructField("firstname",StringType(),True),StructField("middlename",StringType(),True),StructField("lastname",StringType(),True), StructField("id", StringType(), True),StructField("gender", StringType(), True),StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True)])"""
```

Data is:

```
data2 = [
    ("James","","Smith","36636","M",3000),
    ("Michael","Rose","","40288","M",4000),
    ("Robert","","Williams","42114","M",4000),
    ("Maria","Anne","Jones","39192","F",4000),
    ("Jen","Mary","Brown","","F",-1)
]
```

I want to create a dataframe out of it.

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data = data2, schema = schema_str)
```

But this will give an error.
How to create a dataframe ?
Ps:

1. I will have schema in string format only
2. Need to modify it to create the dataframe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manually create a pyspark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959759/manually-create-a-pyspark-dataframe)

Comment: My schema is dynamic so that's why I cannot create manually every time.
Basically I have a CREATE TABLE(..) statement which I am referring to create a schema and it has nested datatypes

Comment: Read again the top answer and you'll have your answer

Answer (score 0):

Pyspark have nice inbuilt method - _parse_datatype_string.
But it takes a simpler string scheme as input, example - "firstname string, middlename string, lastname string, id string, gender string, salary integer".

It should not be difficult for you to bring the source string to this form.