# Convert a Column object to a DataFrame in PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a JSON list which I am reading using `from_json`. How do I convert the resulting Column type to a single-column dataframe?

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType

jsonlist = '["a","b","c"]'
col = from_json(jsonlist , ArrayType(StringType()))

# how to I create a dataframe?
df = ...
```

Everything I  have tried results in

> TypeError: Column is not iterable

eg

```py
spark.createDataFrame([col], ['item'])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manually create a pyspark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959759/manually-create-a-pyspark-dataframe)

Comment: @Steven thanks for the suggestion but it feels like that question and answers start with different data types (eg Row) not a Column

Comment: you just dont create from a column object. Why would you do this ?

Comment: `['a','b','c']` is not a JSON valid format. Strings in JSON should be between double quotes.

Comment: I apologise for getting the quotes the wrong way around in this example

Comment: @Steven I am new to this. When I search for loading JSON in pyspark, this is what I find - the function from_json returns a column object

Comment: to spark, `jsonlist` is a string. neither a json nor a list. `from_json` is a spark function. spark functions can be applied on spark dataframes. *you don't have a dataframe, yet.* create a simple dataframe by reading the string as a string. then, use the mentioned function on the created dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can do this without using a pyspark function to parse the JSON:

```py
import json
json = '["a","b","c"]'
jsonlist = json.loads(json)
df= spark.createDataFrame([x for x in zip(*[iter(jsonlist )])], ['item'])
display(df)
```

Comment: That's exactly why I gave you the "manually create dataframe" link ...

Answer (score 1):

This code do the job:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType
import json

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("JSON to DataFrame") \
    .getOrCreate()
json_string = "['a','b','c']"
json_list = json.loads(json_string.replace("'", "\""))
schema = StructType([
    StructField("Column1", StringType(), True)
])
df = spark.createDataFrame([(value,) for value in json_list], schema=schema)
df.show()
```

Comment: I'm starting with a string representation of a JSON array ie "['a','b','c']" not a list of lists

Comment: I fixed to list